# Append new text fields to various div's in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having some trouble with javascript/jquery. My current situation is as follows
I have multiple div's with text fields.Lets say i am using php loop to display 2 input fields initially in each and every div

```
<div id="somediv100">
  <input type="text" id="name_100_1">
  <input type="text" id="name_100_2">
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="addnew(100)" />
<div id="somediv101">
   <input type="text" id="name_101_1">
   <input type="text" id="name_101_2">
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="addnew(101)" />
```

Now i want to let users add text field in the respective div's when they click addnew button of the respective div.
My main intension is to keep count on how many more fields are added after initial two fields. How can i go about it?
P.S All the values such as 100,101,1,2 etc are produced by php script via looping

Comment: I need to keep track because i have to loop through all the values in another javascript function and send those values via ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/umuvus/1/edit

basically, for a given div:

```
div.data("addedCount");
```

keeps count of the input fields you added

```
div.data("addedCount", div.data("addedCount") + 1);
```

increments that count

```
$("div").data("addedCount", 0);
```

initializes the count

also, if you know for sure the amount of initial input elements for all divs will be the same:

```
div.children("input").length - initialAmount
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep a count of total number of field added by php in hidden field lets say 100. Now when you hit add button use that hidden field count and add +1 to it for every new field you add.

Comment: But i have multiple divs. How can i keep count for every div?

Comment: give each div an id  for example div_1 and so on then you can have a work around with that.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function fnc()
{
    el=document.createElement('div');

    //el.innerHTML="<input type='textbox' name='hid"+(i+1)+"'/>";
    el.innerHTML="<input type='textbox'  />";
    document.getElementById("adiv").appendChild(el);


}
</script>
<form action="CreateDynamicDiv.asp" method="post">
<div id="adiv">
qwerty
</div>
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="fnc();">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

make all the div and textbox dynamically meand

```
    <javascript>
$(document).ready(function(){
for(i=1;<=(how many div you want);i++)
{
<div id=i>
for(j=1;j<=2;j++)
{
<input type='text' id=i+j>
}
</div>
}


});
</javascript>
```